# Images resize when I turn them into links

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making my first portfolio website and I'm trying to use flexbox to create a scrollable gallery of thumbnails. The idea is that you click on an image representing a project which links to the page for that project. I managed to create a flexbox which looks fine when I just insert the images. But when I turn the images into links, the images change size and become tiny. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It's my first question on here so let me know if anything else is needed to help. Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">    
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="15%" height=auto></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
    /*projects menu*/
.container 
{    display: flex;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     margin-bottom: 10%;
     justify-content: center;
}

.container img {margin-right: 15px;}
```

Comment: `auto` isn't a valid value for the `height` attribute in HTML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to provide width for the flexbox item. In your case.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">    
  <a href="#" ><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%"height=auto></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And your css should be

```
    /*projects menu*/
.container 
{    display: flex;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     margin-bottom: 10%;
     justify-content: center;
}

.container a {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width:100%
}
```

Comment: There is no `width` attribute for the `a` element in HTML.

Comment: It worked both ways! (`width=15%` added to the `a` element or to `.container a`)

Comment: @Stegosaurus please upvote or mark as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have added `width=15%` in your `img` tags. Change that to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the width to 100% in image tag solves the issue. I tested the following at codepen.io

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">    
      <a href="#" ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
      <a href="#" ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
      <a href="#" ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="mountains" width="100%"height=auto></a>
      <a href="#" ><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="mountains" width="100%" height=auto></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container 
{    display: flex;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     margin-bottom: 10%;
     justify-content: center;
}

.container a {
  margin-right: 15px;
  width:100%
}
```

Check it at [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/syedaffanhamdani/pen/YzwoJWX).